# Windows can not find javaw.exe

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables, pentaho-spoon

I just try to run spoon.bat but notification says `javaw.exe` does not found, after I read the notification, spoon.bat can not find the `javaw.exe` because the folder was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\bin\javax.exe`, so the problem is **`\bin\bin`** in java folder structure the is no `\bin\bin\` it was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin` , So what can I do to change `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\bin\javaw.exe` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\javaw.exe`

Comment: In Windows, click on System settings.  Then go to advanced system settings and at the bottom click on Environment variables.  From there, correct your search path.  Note that this won't work if your spoon.bat file makes the call using an absolute path name. You may need to edit the .bat file and make appropriate changes there.

Comment: I already set the path in Enviroment variebles but it does not work sir

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what else to suggest,  I edited your tags to try and generate some other suggestions.   You might also try searching for any online help/support in the pentaho-spoon community.

Comment: @Eren_Jaeger_Snk Apart from the problem with setting the path (with which I can't help, sorry), keep in mind that spoon is not certified to work with java 14, you have to work with java 8, refer to Pentaho oficial documentation: https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.2/Setup/Components_Reference, section Java Virtual Machine.